# Small bluetooth device (not off the shelf) which sends a single button input to a phone

Tags: bluetooth

What I need is some bluetooth device, that would accept a single button input and send it via blutooth to my android phone. Example commands might be - to stop playing music, forward to next track or etc.

I have made this illustration to make it more clear - [image]

Just like those selfie stick remotes - [image]
However, I would need to send a different command, than taking a photo and I need a custom self made button (which I will trigger with my toe)

I've tried googling around, and some solutions suggest using Arduino. However I need something smaller. Is there any solution you know of, that is easy to do for an electronic amateur?

Comment: Apparently they just send a keyboard command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741854/how-does-a-remote-shutter-for-camera-work-on-android-ios - it might be easier to remap that in software.

Comment: Please make it clear that you are not looking for an off-the-shelf device.

Comment: @pjc50 Thanks, this might be a very simple solution, I'll look if I can rewire the buttons from them

Comment: You could sacrifice an actual bluetooth keyboard for this. Most of them have tiny PCBs, and you could pick any button you like, provided it is available on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are bluetooth modules that come with small 8051 microcontrollers. This is *not* by any means a company endorsement, but you can start by checking out [bluegiga](http://www.bluegiga.com/) products. Search for any part with some GPIOs and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like these things might have a bit steep learning curve for a beginner, but they look pretty versatile. I'll try this.